# Elasticsearch - higher scoring if higher frequency of term

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have 2 documents, and am searching for the keyword "Twitter". Suppose both documents are blog posts with a "tags" field.

Document A has ONLY 1 term in the "tags" field, and it's "Twitter".
Document B has 100 terms in the "tags" field, but 3 of them is "Twitter".

Elastic Search gives the higher score to Document A even though Document B has a higher frequency. But the score is "diluted" because it has more terms. How do I give Document B a higher score, since it has a higher frequency of the search term?

I know ElasticSearch/Lucene performs some normalization based on the number of terms in the document. How can I disable this normalization, so that Document B gets a higher score above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer says it would be interesting to see whether you have the same result on a single shard. I think you would and that depends on the norms for the tags field, which is taken into account when computing the score using the tf/idf similarity (default).

In fact, lucene does take into account the term frequency, in other words the number of times the term appears within the field (1 or 3 in your case), and the inverted document frequency, in other words how the term is frequent in the index, in order to compare it with other terms in the query (in your case it doesn't make any difference if you are searching for a single term).

But there's another factor called norms, that rewards shorter fields and take into account eventual index time boosting, which can be per field (in the mapping) or even per document. You can verify that norms are the reason of your result enabling the explain option in your search request and looking at the explain output.

I guess the fact that the first document contains only that tag makes it more important that the other ones that contains that tag multiple times but a lot of ther tags as well. If you don't like this behaviour you can just disable norms in your mapping for the tags field. It should be enabled by default if the field is `"index":"analyzed"` (default). You can either switch to `"index":"not_analyzed"` if you don't want your tags field to be analyzed (it usually makes sense but depends on your data and domain) or add the `"omit_norms": true` option in the mapping for your tags field.

Answer (score 0):

Are the documents found on different shards? From Elastic search documentation:

"When a query is executed on a specific shard, it does not take into account term frequencies and other search engine information from the other shards. If we want to support accurate ranking, we would need to first execute the query against all shards and gather the relevant term frequencies, and then, based on it, execute the query."

The solution is to specify the search type. Use dfs_query_and_fetch search type to execute  an initial scatter phase which goes and computes the distributed term frequencies for more accurate scoring.

You can read more [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/).