# elasticsearch function score, boost weight of "number of matched terms in query" (coordination)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch function score for customized scoring and these are my priorities for ranking:

1. number of common terms with query (for example a document which has 3 of 4 terms in query should be ranked higher than a document which has 2 of 4 terms in query, no matter how much is tf/idf score of each term). in elastic documentation it's called [coordination factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#coord).
2. sum of relevancy of terms. (tf/idf)
3. document popularity (number of votes for each document as described in [boosting by popularity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html))

This is the body of request for elasticsearch currently used:

```
body = {
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    {'match': {'text': query}}
                },
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                            "field": "ducoumnet_popularity",
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that first priority is not satisfied with this request. for example there could be document A which has less common terms with query than document B, but because its common terms have more tf/idf score, document A is ranked higher than document B.

To prevent this I think the best way is to boost score of documents by coordination factor. is there any way to do this? something similar to this request:

```
body = {
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    {'match': {'text': query}}
                },
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                            "field": "ducoumnet_popularity",
                        },
                        "field_value_factor": {
                            "field": "_coordination"
                            "weight": 10
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you get the answer to this?

Comment: @ayushsinghal no :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch - higher scoring if higher frequency of term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631026/elasticsearch-higher-scoring-if-higher-frequency-of-term)

Comment: It is a duplicate, but even if the other question as been marked as answered by the OP, I don't find it to be a satisfactory answer. Their is no solution offered to re-weight the different elements of the score.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find exact answer for this question but it may help someone to know that you can limit minimum precision for documents in result using  `minimum_should_match`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "content": {
                "query": "quick brown dog",
                "minimum_should_match": 75%
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it accept many different configuration. more explanation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html